# the version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid or cannot be read

Tags: sql-server, reporting

Has anyone come across this message before?

> the version of the report server database is either in a format that
> is not valid or cannot be read. The found version is 165. The expected
> version is 163.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade?

Comment: No, here is what I did:  The report server url stopped working all of a sudden, Microsoft suggested to uninstall the reporting services and re-install, I took the backup of report server db, report server tempdb and encryption key, after the re-installation of reporting services, I restored the db's but when I tried to restored the encryption key, I started getting that error.

Comment: It looks like you have to patch newly installed SSRS (version 163) before restoring original db (version 165) from backup.